# Where can I find recent snowfall totals for a city?

Tags: webapp-rec

I'm trying to find a place that shows how much snow has fallen in the last few days. Reports from amateur weather stations (such as in-home or at schools) are fine. If possible, I'd like to know what it is for my city or ZIP code, or a neighboring city or zip code, rather than for the metro area.

I've been able to find plenty of similar information that doesn't work; I'm not looking for any of the following:

- Ski resort totals
- Snow accumulations *(I'd have to know how much snow was on the ground before, and how much snow melted to get what I'm looking for.)*
- Simple precipitation totals *(As far as I understand, this really only tells how wet the snow was, or the amount of water if you melted down the snow.)*
- Snowfall totals that don't go past the last 24 hours *(That won't catch storms that last several days)*

I've tried Wolfram Alpha, local news sites, and a few weather sites like Weather.com, Weather Underground, and AccuWeather. However, I wouldn't be surprised if I'm just not looking in the right place there.

Comment: Not for your city but a good example: http://www.tomscott.com/weather/starwars/ :)

Comment: NOAA? http://www.hpc.ncep.noaa.gov/wwd/winter_wx.shtml

Comment: @edelwater, the Star Wars weather example is humorous, but I don't see any snowfall totals on that site. Thanks!

Comment: @edelwater The NOAA page had snowfall *forecasts,* which aren't what I'm looking for. I tried the "Recent Snowfall and Snow Depth Maps" link, and it was *really* close to what I wanted, but its scope was limited enough that I couldn't find any measurements near my city. Thank you, though!

Comment: well... if NOAA doesnt have it...

Comment: @edelwater, that's a good point, but I'm still convinced it's out there; my local news often has that sort of info on TV broadcasts, but they don't post it on their website.

Comment: @edelwater, I found it on the NOAA site today. I don't remember what term I searched the Internet using, and it wasn't linked from the link you gave me, but you were right that the NOAA would have it if anyone did. See my answer below.

Comment: Last night, ~13cm around Lake Geneva, does that help? :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how I found it, but [the NOAA U.S. Daily Snowfall and Snow Depth Data page](http://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/snow-and-ice/dly-data.php) gives snowfall totals and snow depth totals, per day, for many stations per state. It has several missing data points, but that's to be expected. It's not the cleanest, easiest to read, or most webapp-like site, though. The data are displayed in long text file tables.

A couple more links for recent snowfall.

[Recent Snowfall](http://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/snow-and-ice/recent.php)

[Dynamic Map](http://gis.ncdc.noaa.gov/maps/snowfall.map?view=daily)

Comment: I'd certainly be happy to know if there was a site that had this data displayed in a nicer format, so please answer if you know of one.

Answer (score -1):

Try WolframAlpha. Example: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=annual+snowfall+san+francisco%2C+ca

Comment: The WolframAlpha results are quite nice, but my results say "(estimated with water equivalent of snow)", and clicking "More" for more detail doesn't present the snowfall total. Thanks, though!